# MDI form with login form does not return to login after closing MDI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have an MDI form that the user can access after login, when the user closes session it should go back to the login form instead it opens the login form and immediately closes it and the MDI form, too.

I am just calling the `Close()` method when the user click the log off button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're doing it but I would say to use something like this

```
//on login form
private void Login()
{
   //check if the login is right
   MdiForm formName = new MdiForm();
   this.Hide(); // so the Login Form is not visible
   formName.ShowDialog(); //opens the mdi and does whatever it needs
   this.Show(); //after the mdi closes go back to here
}
```